# Strict null check not working on typescript in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm brand new to Typescript and I suppose this is basic, but I was watching 2017 What's new in Typescript video here:  [Build 2017 with  Anders Hejlsberg][1] and the section on null checking looked interesting but doesn't work for me in VS Code for some reason

I have `"strictNullChecks": true` in my tsconfig.json, and I am using the latest version of tsc I can find (3.7.3), but when I have code like this as a method in a class in my code there are no complaints from the compiler like in the demo.  Since this was a 2017 video I assume all this has been released by now.  Can someone explain?

```
 foo(a?: string) : string {
    return a;
 }
```

Comment: Seems like your `strictNullChecks` option does not get picked up.

Comment: Could you share your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Make sure your tsconfig.json is called exactly that (tsconfig.app.json won't get picked up by the language service) and also that it is in the root directory of the opened project.

Comment: "also that it is in the root directory of the opened project"

 thank you!